# Testing a google firebase connection

Tags: java, unix, firebase, firebase-authentication

is there a way to test a google fire base connection from the UNIX command line?

I am working on an executable jar file, which works great locally, but cannot write to fire base. So I would like to find a way to test the connection.

I can ping my fire base url from the server.

thank you,

Comment: There's a REST API for the Firebase Database that you could use from the command line: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see lots of details about the state of the SDK's connection to Firebase, turn on debug logging.  You can do that with [FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Doug, this was exactly what I needed. It also helped me pinpoint the issue. I was simply unaware of the logging method for firebase.

---

For others who might have issues implementing:

Import Statement: (eclipse gives you options in my case)

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level;
```

Set Doug's Log Level:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(fbconn).setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

Proceed to try to make your connection: (fbconn is FirebaseApp that I set with my details for firebase)

```
FirebaseDatabase defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(fbconn);
String strCurrentTimestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss a").format(new Date());  
DatabaseReference dataRef = defaultDatabase.getReference().child("Firebase-Connection-Verified");
dataRef.setValue(strCurrentTimestamp);
```